# Can't access the data in Kafka Spark Streaming globally

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to Streaming the data from Kafka to Spark

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, 
                String.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                kafkaParams, topics);
```

Here i am iterating over the JavaPairInputDStream to process the RDD's.

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd ->{
            rdd.foreachPartition(items ->{
                while (items.hasNext()) {
                    String[] State = items.next()._2.split("\\,");
                    System.out.println(State[2]+","+State[3]+","+State[4]+"--");
                };
            });        
        });
```

I can able to fetch the data in foreachRDD and my requirement is have to access State Array globally. When i am trying to access the State Array globally i am getting Exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: 'to access State Array globally' means? outside `directKafkaStream.foreachRDD`? I don't think it's possible. If you could explain your actual use case(what do you want to do with global State array), I might be able to suggest better solutions.

Comment: YEs exactly @Darshan i need to "access State Array globally". My usecase is:  I had a lookup table with 4 coulumns [Code, Definition, Manhattan_Area, Other_states] in Hive. In streaming data i had 3 columns [State, IssueDate, ViolationCode].  I want to perform an operation like calculate sum of amount that government is generating per each violation code for each day based on state.

Comment: Which field in hive is your lookup field? and which field in stream data are you looking up against? And how does having state[] as global variable help you? It seems the way you are using spark streaming is wrong.

Comment: Code [HiveLookUpField] and ViolationCode[in Stream Data]

Comment: i can read the data like this from hive
Dataset<Row> ds = session.sql("select * from lookup");
So if i can access the streaming data globally so i can match the data from 2 tables.

Comment: Can you share your emailid so i can explain more clear....

Comment: I am new to Hive so I don't think I will be able to provide you actual code snippets anyway. So I have added a flow that should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a joining your lookup table with streaming RDD to get all the items that have a matching 'code' and 'violationCode' fields.

The flow should be like this.

1. Create an RDD of Hive lookup table => lookupRdd
2. Create DStream from kafka stream
3. For each RDD in Dstream, join lookupRDD with streamRdd, process the joined items(calculate sum of amount...) and save this processed result.

**Note** Below code is incomplete. Please complete all the TODO comments.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> streamPair = directKafkaStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Tuple2 Message is----------" + tuple2._2());
            String[] state = tuple2._2.split("\\,");
            return new Tuple2<>(state[4], tuple2._2()); //pair <ViolationCode, data>
        }
    });

    streamPair.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Void>() {
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> hivePairRdd = null;
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> stringStringJavaPairRDD) throws Exception {
            if (hivePairRdd == null) {
                hivePairRdd = initHiveRdd();
            }
            JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, String>> joinedRdd = stringStringJavaPairRDD.join(hivePairRdd);
            System.out.println(joinedRdd.take(10));
            //todo process joinedRdd here and save the results.
            joinedRdd.count(); //to trigger an action
            return null;
        }
    });
}

public static JavaPairRDD<String, String> initHiveRdd() {
    JavaRDD<String> hiveTableRDD = null; //todo code to create RDD from hive table
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> hivePairRdd = hiveTableRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(String row) throws Exception {
            String code = null; //TODO process 'row' and get 'code' field
            return new Tuple2<>(code, row);
        }
    });
    return hivePairRdd;
}
```

Comment: is the way you said ?


`JavaDStream<String> lines = directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
     
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Override
     public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
            System.out.println("Tuple2 Message is----------"+tuple2._2());
      return tuple2._2();
     }
    });`

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Please edit it according to your needs.